# Yii2 MINIMIZING THE ASSETS IN YII 2 FRAMEWORK

Tags: php, yii, compression

I am trying to minimize the assets in yii2 test project, but with no result. I used this tutorial: https://www.dunebook.com/how-to-minimize-the-assets-in-yii-2-framework/2/. I use openserver. In assets directory I created a file named compression. In that file I put yuicompressor.jar(YUI compressor) and compiler.jar(Google Closure compiler). After that, I tried to create configuration file for the compressor

running this command in the openserver console(being in the project root):

```
$ ./yii asset/template assets/compression/config.php. But here I get the following error: 
"$" Is not internal or external
Command, executable program or batch file.
```

Please help with this!